# compare rows and update if different values and insert if doesn't exist

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a TABLE1 and TABLE2 with same columns(around 15) except TABLE2 has additional date fields. I am trying to loop through TABLE1(around 25,000) rows and insert into TABLE2 if row doesn't exist. 
This can be done without any issues but I would like to update TABLE2 only if any column value is different from TABLE1. Do I have to check manually compare each column value and update? I couldn't find any easier ways to do this. The reason I would like to do this because I want to insert a row into a History table only when there is any update or insert.

```
begin
   update table set ...
   where key = @key
end
else
begin
   insert into table (key, ...)
   values (@key, ...)
end
```

Comment: Search on upsert.  It is done with merge https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for recommending MERGE because that is a correct method that can handle both instances in a single statement. If you are not familiar with it, you can run two separate statements (UPDATE/INSERT).

For **UPDATING**:

If you want to update based on any column not being equal based on whatever key you have joined to is fairly simple. You can get a list of all columns from either table (easiest is to right click the table and SELECT TOP 1000).

Highlight the columns and press Shift + Tab and remove all commas with a CTRL + F, Replace All. Copy and Paste that into Excel, column A.

Insert the following formula in column B:

B1: `="T1."&A1&" <> T2."&A1&","`

B2: `="OR T1."&A2&" = T2."&A2&","`

Copy and paste the formula in B2 all the way down the list. So:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.Column1 = T2.Column1
    ,T1.Column2 = T2.Column2
    ,T1.Column3 = T2.Column3
    ,T1.Column4 = T2.Column4
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.Table1PrimaryKey = T2.Table2PrimaryKey
WHERE T1.Column1 <> T2.Column1
    OR T1.Column2 <> T2.Column2
    OR T1.Column3 <> T2.Column3
    OR T1.Column4 <> T2.Column4
```

Note: Since all columns being compared are being updated if any column combination doesn't match then you are fine because updating a column that matches will not hurt anything. And, if you are implementing a slowly changing dimension where you track the date change then the updated date is still valid because at least **one** column record did not match and was thus updated.

For **INSERTING**:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4)
SELECT T2.Column1
    ,T2.Column2
    ,T2.Column3
    ,T2.Column4
FROM Table2 T2
WHERE T2.Table2PrimaryKey NOT EXISTS (SELECT T1.Table1PrimaryKey FROM Table1 T1)
ORDER BY T2.Table2PrimaryKey
```

Note: The above INSERT assumes that your PrimaryKey column is an IDENTITY column, which cannot be INSERTED on because it is auto calculated. In the event that you are using a primary key that is not an IDENTITY field then you will need to include it into the INSERT clause. Also, the ORDER BY will INSERT the records in order of the PRIMARY KEY. This is useful when the PRIMARY KEY is an IDENTITY field because the calculated value will at least be in order of where it came from. In the event that all INSERTS use this methodology AND the destination table receives records only from the receiving table AND there have been neither any RESEEDS nor deletions, then the IDENTITY Primary key column value will be identical.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do it column at a time
If you have some null you need to do checks for that

```
insert into history 
select t1.id, t1.col1, t2.col1  
from table2 t2 
join table1 t1 
  on t2.id = t1.id  
 and t1.col1 <> t2.col 

update t2 
set t2.col1 = t1.col1 
from table2 t2 
join table1 t1 
  on t2.id = t1.id 
 and t1.col1 <> t2.col
```

You could also just do the update with an ouput clause

For the insert use `not exists`

Comment: Well are you going to know which column was updated from the time stamp?  Sorry I could not have been of more assistance to you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is something you need to do more than once, I would suggest you use an insert and an update trigger on table A, that keeps table B up to date.